# How to upgrade sonar from 5.6 to 6.7 with dedicated database

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using 5.6 version of sonar, want to upgrade to 6.7. Can I directly upgraded to 6.7 ?

I have 8-10 sonar projects hosted on a same instance of sonar server. I am not sure what would break after upgrade.  I am thinking of following approach

1. Install (do not upgrade) a new version of sonar 6.7, this would run on the different port(s).
2. Create a copy of sonar database which I have with my older sonar version, attach that copy of DB to new installation of sonar (by updating the sonar configuration file).
3. Assuming everything works fine, retire the older version (sonar server & DB).

I am using dedicated database as SQL server.

Anybody tried this approach? does it work?

Atul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using one of the [supported databases](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements#Requirements-HardwareRequirements), you can upgrade directly from 5.6 to 6.7.

Simply follow the [Upgrade Guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) - and make sure that you back up your DB first in case of troubles.

Comment: I would take the backup first, one more question: Can two instances of Sonar points to same dedicated database copy. one version is 5.6 & other is 6.7. Each sonar instance would run on separate port.  Instance of creating a copy of a database I am thinking of using same instance across multiple version of sonar. Appreciate your response.

Comment: No, this is not possible to run 2 SonarQube instances pointed to the same DB schema.